# Php Local Host and server are different result

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, error-handling

I have created script for lk domain search.

this is the code

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="dm" placeholder="tx">
</form>

<?php 

if (isset($_GET["dm"])) {

    $domain = $_GET["dm"];

    $res = file_get_contents("https://www.domains.lk/domainsearch/doDomainSearch?domainname=$domain");

    echo $domain;
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var data = '<?php echo $res ?>';

    document.write(data);

</script>
```

var data will show in local host. but i have hosted it in my server then result will not show.

this is server hosted file http://vishmaloke.com/dm/ser.php

Comment: Make sure you have the extension `php_openssl.dll` enabled in your server's `php.ini` file. You will have to restart your web server (Apache/Nginx) afterwards.

Comment: Look at the error logs. There must be a description of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLUTION #1**

There is PHP setting by name `allow_url_fopen`. This must be enable to get content from remote url. You can do it via `.htaccess` file.

Put following line in an `.htaccess` file in the directory you want the setting to be enabled:

```
php_value allow_url_fopen On
```

**Note**: This above setting will apply only into same directory where `.htaccess` file placed.

---

> **SOLUTION #2**

Alternatively you can update `php.ini`

**PHP.INI UPDATE**

add following line to `php.ini`

```
allow_url_fopen = On;
```

---

> **SOLUTION 3**

It is recommended to use `curl` instead of `file_get_contents`

**CURL UPDATE**

```
if (isset($_GET["dm"]))
{

    $domain = $_GET["dm"];

    // curl
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.domains.lk/domainsearch/doDomainSearch?domainname=$domain");
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $res = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);


    echo $domain;
}
```

Comment: This might be not only one problem.

Comment: @Pyton I agree but this is the most common issue in such cases